# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError returned when calling native method

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a Java wrapper for a third party DLL. I created my own DLL that acts as a middle man between JNI and the third party DLL. In java I load this DLL fine but the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  sixense.Sixense.init()Z` is returned. What could be causing this error and how can I debug it properly?

Main.java:

```
package sixense_test;

import sixense.ControllerData;
import sixense.Sixense;

public class Main {

    public static ControllerData[] controllers = new ControllerData[4];
    public static boolean quit;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(Sixense.init()) {
            Sixense.setActiveBase(0);
            Sixense.getAllNewestData(controllers);
            System.out.println("X: " + controllers[0].pos[0] + "Y: " + controllers[0].pos[1] + "Z: " + controllers[0].pos[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Sixense.java:

```
package sixense;

public class Sixense {
    public static native boolean init();
    public static native boolean exit();
    public static native int getMaxBases();
    public static native boolean setActiveBase( int base_num );
    public static native boolean isBaseConnected( int base_num );
    public static native int getMaxControllers();
    public static native int getNumActiveControllers();
    public static native boolean isControllerEnabled( int controller_id );
    public static native boolean getAllNewestData( ControllerData[] all_data );
    public static native boolean getAllData( int index_back, ControllerData[] all_data );
    public static native boolean getNewestData( int controller_id, ControllerData data );
    public static native boolean getData( int controller_id, int index_back, ControllerData all_data );
    public static native int getHistorySize();
    public static native boolean setFilterEnabled( boolean on_or_off );
    public static native boolean getFilterEnabled();
    public static native boolean setFilterParams( float near_range, float near_val, float far_range, float far_val );
    public static native boolean getFilterParams( float[] params );
    public static native boolean triggerVibration( int controller_id, int duration, int pattern_id );
    public static native boolean autoEnableHemisphereTracking( int controller_id );
    public static native boolean setHighPriorityBinding( boolean on_or_off );
    public static native boolean getHighPriorityBinding();
    public static native boolean setBaseColor( int red, int green, int blue );
    public static native boolean getColorBase( int[] colors );
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Sixense_Java");
    }
}
```

An excerpt from sixense_Sixense.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <sixense.h>
#include "sixense_Sixense.h"

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_sixense_Sixense_init(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj) {
    int i;
    i = sixenseInit();
    return (i == -1) ? JNI_FALSE : JNI_TRUE;
}
```

An excerpt from sixense_Sixense.h:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class sixense_Sixense */

#ifndef _Included_sixense_Sixense
#define _Included_sixense_Sixense
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     sixense_Sixense
 * Method:    init
 * Signature: ()Z
 */
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_sixense_Sixense_init
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

Output from dumpbin:

```
File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for Sixense_Java.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    4FFBC481 time date stamp Tue Jul 10 01:58:25 2012
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
          23 number of functions
          23 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001D10 Java_sixense_Sixense_autoEnableHemisphereTracking@12
          2    1 000011A0 Java_sixense_Sixense_exit@8
          3    2 00001A40 Java_sixense_Sixense_getAllData@16
          4    3 000019A0 Java_sixense_Sixense_getAllNewestData@12
          5    4 00001DC0 Java_sixense_Sixense_getColorBase@12
          6    5 00001B30 Java_sixense_Sixense_getData@20
          7    6 00001BD0 Java_sixense_Sixense_getFilterEnabled@8
          8    7 00001C40 Java_sixense_Sixense_getFilterParams@12
          9    8 00001D60 Java_sixense_Sixense_getHighPriorityBinding@8
         10    9 00001B90 Java_sixense_Sixense_getHistorySize@8
         11    A 000011C0 Java_sixense_Sixense_getMaxBases@8
         12    B 00001210 Java_sixense_Sixense_getMaxControllers@8
         13    C 00001AE0 Java_sixense_Sixense_getNewestData@16
         14    D 00001220 Java_sixense_Sixense_getNumActiveControllers@8
         15    E 00001180 Java_sixense_Sixense_init@8
         16    F 000011F0 Java_sixense_Sixense_isBaseConnected@12
         17   10 00001230 Java_sixense_Sixense_isControllerEnabled@12
         18   11 000011D0 Java_sixense_Sixense_setActiveBase@12
         19   12 00001D90 Java_sixense_Sixense_setBaseColor@20
         20   13 00001BA0 Java_sixense_Sixense_setFilterEnabled@12
         21   14 00001C00 Java_sixense_Sixense_setFilterParams@24
         22   15 00001D30 Java_sixense_Sixense_setHighPriorityBinding@12
         23   16 00001CE0 Java_sixense_Sixense_triggerVibration@20

  Summary

        1000 .bss
        1000 .data
        1000 .edata
        1000 .idata
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        2000 .text
```

Comment: Do you have the folder with the dlls in your -Djava.library.path VM arg?

Comment: What does dumpbin /exports Sixense_Java.dll report?

Comment: The DLLs are in the a folder that is part of the java.library.path and @Petesh I have just added the output of dumpbin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When calling a native function in Java, the runtime tries to use:

- a stdcall-style decorated function: `_functionName@n`, where n is the number of bytes in the parameter list,
- and a cdecl-style undecorated function: `functionName`.

When compiling with MinGW, you will get a mix of these two: MinGW will append the `@n`, but will not prepend the underscore: `functionName@n`.

The way to solve this is to tell `ld` not to add the suffix, using the `--kill-at` switch (or `-Wl,--kill-at` if you call it through GCC).

Comment: Could you go a little more in depth with your answer? I'm having the same problem as OP, I'm using a makefile to call javah to generate the header and g++ to generate the .o and .dll. I am using MinGW yet `@n` is not appended to any function names, neither is an underscore prepended, though unlike the OP simply modifying the files (I know, really shouldn't do it) doesn't actually help.

Comment: For maximum compatibility, one can also specify `--add-stdcall-alias`. With CMake, this is possible via `set_target_properties (target PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias")`.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer! It seems that when using JNI in Windows it looks for a function starting with `_Java_` while in every other platform it looks for `Java_`. Why this is the case and not written in the documentation I don't know but it make everything work perfectly!

Comment: So how did you fix it exactly? Changed dll compilation flags?

Comment: When javah creates the header file each function is named like `Java_package_Class_method`. The odd thing is that when compiled like this, JNI cannot find the right function for the native method and spits out errors, but if an underscore was added before `Java`  then JNI would be able to find the function. On a side note I have since tried compiling with VC++2010 (I was using MinGW before) and the underscores were a problem when compiled then. Go figure.

Comment: Leading underscore is a known stdcall name decoration for MSVC. It's no problem as long as you compile and use against the same and one JDK (jni.h is a key). On the other hand, MinGW has no such decoration and doesn't expect it. You perhaps somehow mixed up the two environments or the calling conventions. Wild guess. But hacking your created header is not a solution. The "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE" comment really has a reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Sixense_Java in java.library.path
```

Looks like Java cant find the library, did you put it in the right place?

You might need to change the `java.library.path`, take a look at [this](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_499.asp).

If you want to print the contents of it use:

```
System.out.println( System.getProperties().getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

This might print a lot, you might want to `split(";")` and print each entry on its own.

Comment: That error was only outputted when I deleted the library to test if it sent a different error message.

Comment: I just noticed that Sixense_init requests two parameters, you are calling it without them though. This might be the reason why the function cannot be found.

Comment: The way that JNI works is that each native function is sent JNIEnv and a reference to the class that called the function as well as any additional parameters. JNI takes care of sending JNIEnv and the class reference on it's own.