# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError from native method after System.load returned success

Tags: java, java-web-start, loadlibrary

I have a java web start app that extracts a dll from itself to a temp file, and loads it via System.load("full\path\to\dll").

That completes successfully.  However, when I try to invoke the native methods in that dll, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError with the name of the method.

This is a Windows 7 box, 32 bit 1.7.0_45 (and _51) jre's.  This same code works everywhere else except for some computers for 1 customer.

Supposedly the accounts have no local admin permissions (that's normal) and are running Microsoft Security Center Endpoint Protection.  Is there some conflict between MS EPP and java's LoadLibrary calls?  My google-fu couldn't find it if there is.  Or what else could explain this problem?

At first the dll wasn't signed (it's never had to be before), but I tried signing it with our code signing cert to see if that had anything to do with it, but no help.

Comment: After more reading, it seems as though maybe RegisterNatives isn't being automatically called.  I don't provide a JNI_OnLoad or call RegisterNatives myself.  I've never needed to before, but I may end up trying that...

Comment: Why user this broken method for loading a native as opposed to the standard way for a JWS app.?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Because it's always been that way and it was inherited from a non webstart app all the way back from java 1.3.  Basically, it wasn't broken, so we never touched it.  I'm setting up a nativelib test now to see if that helps.

Comment: @AndrewThompson:  I've converted the code to use nativelib resources and a simple System.loadLibrary() call, which is much cleaner, but still fails the same way.  The load library succeeds, but the calls to the native methods fail with a UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420153/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-returned-when-calling-native-method

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a late followup, but the solution to the problem related to AppSense.  It was silently interfering with the load library call because the DLL was being extracted to a temp directory and that violated their policy.  The effect was that the library loaded but appeared empty.

We had to sign the dll with our code signing certificate (which the jar's were already signed with), and the customer's AppSense team had to add a rule to allow our signed DLLs to be loaded.

It was a maddening problem.  Hopefully this followup helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all just put the library file into the application
>   directory.(ie App Path) Then use System.load(dll_name.dll).It will
>   surely success. Please check the OS you are using.

1. For Windows :- Library extension is ".dll"
2. For Linux :- Library extension is ".so"

> So the ".dll" in Linux will give the UnSatisfiedLinkError(Vice versa).
>   Then also check for the processor Architecture like.

1. x86
2. x64

Comment: This is windows, and I have a .dll.  This has worked fine for years, but only fails on a subset of new users.  And the loadLibrary works, but the native methods just dont seem to connect.

Comment: What fo you mean " **but the native methods just dont seem to connect.** "

Comment: I mean the loadLibrary() method returns ok, but then it's as if the automatic RegisterNatives calls don't happen.  My next approach will be to explicitly define JNI_OnLoad and call RegisterNatives myself.  perhaps that will give some error feedback i can use...

Comment: Now you have said that thr System.loadLibrary is ok.Then as ur question states it is already solved.Because the Unsatisfied link error will occur when only at the time of loadLibrary.Now please post the exception you got when calling the native method.

Comment: System.loadLibrary returns ok.  when i try and call the native method,  I get: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.xyz.WinHelp.getktok(Ljava/lang/String;[B)Ljava/lang/Object;`

Comment: Provide a full stacktrace.

Comment: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.xyz.WinHelp.toFront(Ljava/awt/Frame;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
com.xyz.WinHelp.toFront(Native Method)
com.xyz.WinHelp.toFront(SourceFile:248)
com.xyz.auth.c$1.run(SourceFile:68)
java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)`